# spinner получение результатов в ProgressBar

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, progress-bar, android-spinner

Есть spinner ,так же есть RecyclerView  в нем ProgressBar  при выборе в спинере например 2 позиции progressBar должен получить данную позицию и сразу же изменится.Как это реализовать?

```
public class PCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PCAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<PC> dataSet;
private Boolean check=true;
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView word,meaning,tdp,CoresThreads,Socket, Segment,Source,tv_progress_horizontal,e1,e2;
    ProgressBar progressBar1;

    RelativeLayout expandable,cv1;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.expandable= (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
        this.cv1= (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv1);
        this.word= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordtext);

        this.progressBar1= (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        this.tv_progress_horizontal= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress_horizontal);

        this.meaning = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.meaningtext);
        this.tdp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tdp);
        this.CoresThreads = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CoresThreads);
        this.Socket = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Socket);
        this.Segment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Segment);
        this.Source = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Source);
        this.e1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.e1);
        this.e2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.e2);
    }
}

public PCAdapter(ArrayList<PC> data) {
    this.dataSet = data;
}

@Override
public PCAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row1, parent, false);

    final PCAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new PCAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(check)
            {
                myViewHolder.expandable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myViewHolder.expandable.animate()
                        .alpha(1.0f)
                        .setDuration(1000);
                check=false;
            }
            else{
                myViewHolder.cv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.asa1);
                myViewHolder.expandable.animate()
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setDuration(000);
                myViewHolder.expandable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                check=true;
            }
        }
    });

    return myViewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PCAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    TextView word1= holder.word;
    TextView tv_progress_horizontal1= holder.tv_progress_horizontal;
    ProgressBar progressBar1= holder.progressBar1;
    TextView meaning1 = holder.meaning;
    TextView tdp1 = holder.tdp;
    TextView CoresThreads1 = holder.CoresThreads;
    TextView Socket1 = holder.Socket;
    TextView Segment1 = holder.Segment;
    TextView Source1 = holder.Source;

    TextView e11 = holder.e1;
    TextView e21 = holder.e2;


    word1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getWord());
    tv_progress_horizontal1.setText(String.valueOf(dataSet.get(listPosition).getF()));
    progressBar1.setProgress(dataSet.get(listPosition).getProgress());
    meaning1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getMeaning());
    tdp1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getTdp());
    CoresThreads1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getCoresThreads());
    Socket1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getSocket());
    Segment1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getSegment());
    Source1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getSource());
    e11.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getE1());
    e21.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getE2());

    ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(progressBar1, 0,dataSet.get(listPosition).getProgress() );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    progressBar1.startAnimation(anim);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
```

}

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
 MaterialSpinner spinner1;
Intent intent;;
private int mCount=0;
private ArrayList<PC> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PCAdapter mAdapter;

PC movie;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abba);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new PCAdapter(movieList);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

     spinner1 = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    spinner1.setItems("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

        @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, final int position, long id, String item) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(position==0)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==1)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==2)
            {
                  mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==3)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==4)
            { mCount = position;

            }
            else if(position==5)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==6)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==7)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
            else if(position==8)
            {
                mCount = position;
            }
        }

    });

    movie = new PC("  ",mCount,mCount, "", "", "", "", "", "","","");
    movieList.add(movie);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Задайте нормально вопрос, что значит появиться? Они есть но спрятаны?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko исправил

Comment: @0xdb   исправил  и добавил код

Comment: @fcbarcafc Молодец, стало лучше, но я не стану голосовать за повторное открытие. В вопросе не написано, в чем проблема. Кроме того, твой [mcve] явно недостаточно минимален

Comment: @Darth при выборе в спинере например 2 позиции progressBar должен получить данную позицию и сразу же изменится,ВОТ в чем проблема как это реализовать,все доступно и понятно написал

Answer (score 1):

```
int spinnerItem = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
textView.setText((spinnerItem+1).toString());
```

Comment: исправил и добавил код

Answer (score 0):

Вешаете слушатель на спинер и реагируете на нажатие.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
         //тут реагируете на нажатие, "position" - это позиция в самом спинере,
         //начинается с "0" (если не ошибаюсь)
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: исправил и добавил код